# Python Flask cannot get element from form

Tags: python, flask

Im having trouble getting anything from the shown HTML form

I always get "ValueError: View function did not return a response"

Can somebody help me out here please? I have tried every variation of request.get that I can find on the web. Also if I specify my form should use post it uses get anyway - anybody know why this is?

Im new to flask so forgive my ignorance!

Thanks in advance.

The python file (routes.py)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os
app = Flask(__name__)     
musicpath = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Oscar\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music")
lsize = str(len(musicpath))
looper = len(musicpath)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', lsize=20, looper=looper, musicpath=musicpath)

@app.route('/pop', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def pop():
    if request.method == "GET":
      text = request.args.get('som')
      return text
      #Have tried every variation of request.get

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    name = "Hello!"
    return render_template('about.html', name=name)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The html file (home.html)

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="jumbo">
    <h2>A Music app!<h2>
  </div>
  <div>
        {% if lsize %}
            <form action="/pop">
                <select id="som" size="20">
                {% for i in range(looper):%}
                    <option value="{{i}}">{{ musicpath[i] }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <a href="{{ url_for('pop') }}">Select,</a>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: For the `/pop` route, when the method is post, there is not response returned, is this the reason for the problem? Also, paste the full error log would be helpful, instead of one line.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `name` attribute on your `select` element. That is the attribute that browsers use to send information in forms; without it no data will be sent.

Note also that your `pop` handler does not do anything if the method is POST, even though you explicitly say you accept that method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I tried it with a name tag prior to posting and the error is the same. I also had a handler for Post however even if I specify that POST should be used the program uses get regardless...

Comment: Well, that doesn't happen. Please show the code you used when you had the name attribute and you used POST.